# Get a value from JSON array in PHP

Tags: php, html, json

I have a JSON array returned by an API. I need to get the "value" and "value_high" part from the JSON under the Mann Co Supply Crate Key.

I have made a script that gets the values of the ['response']['success'] but I can't get any other values.

```
{
    "response": {
        "success": 1,
        "current_time": 1401869275,
        "raw_usd_value": 0.245,
        "usd_currency": "metal",
        "usd_currency_index": 5002,
        "items": {
            "Mann Co. Supply Crate Key": {
                "defindex": [
                    5021
                ],
                "prices": {
                    "6": {
                        "Tradable": {
                            "Craftable": [
                                {
                                    "item_name": "Mann Co. Supply Crate Key",
                                    "quality": 6,
                                    "craftable": "Craftable",
                                    "tradable": "Tradable",
                                    "priceindex": 0,
                                    "defindex": [
                                        5021
                                    ],
                                    "value": 8.22,
                                    "currency": "metal",
                                    "value_high": 8.33,
                                    "last_update": 1401486984,
                                    "difference": 0.22
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
```

Comment: Instead of down voting maybe people should offer some feedback

Comment: `$data = json_decode($return_Value_from_api, true);` this converts that to an array

Comment: i have already done that. If you read the post it says i can get a value from one part but not the other.

Comment: How can i get the value from "value" and "value_high"

Comment: Show the code you already have please to get the value of success

Comment: PHP as so in the title. http://pastebin.com/XAtdFGPe

Comment: which `value` and `value_high` do you need to get? as in all?

Comment: did you try json_decode? what did you try so far? that's why you get downvoted...

Comment: just the one for the item 'Mann Co. Supply Crate Key'

Comment: @pc-shooter if you read it you would see that i can do that part but i cannot get the value from the array

Comment: @pc-shooter you shouldn't have lambasted.  lack of knowledge ? I feel that is too harsh. No one is good at everything and every one lacks in some point.

Comment: @shatheesh Agree with you, but the OP didn't even try something, and shouts about downvoting and not reading hes question... but maybe you're right, I'll delete my comment then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you need to format your json properly (remove unneccessary comma, add missing `}`):

```
{
        "response": {
            "success": 1,
            "current_time": 1401869275,
            "raw_usd_value": 0.245,
            "usd_currency": "metal",
            "usd_currency_index": 5002,
            "items": {
                "Mann Co. Supply Crate Key": {
                    "defindex": [
                        5021
                    ],
                    "prices": {
                        "6": {
                            "Tradable": {
                                "Craftable": [
                                    {
                                        "item_name": "Mann Co. Supply Crate Key",
                                        "quality": 6,
                                        "craftable": "Craftable",
                                        "tradable": "Tradable",
                                        "priceindex": 0,
                                        "defindex": [
                                            5021
                                        ],
                                        "value": 8.22,
                                        "currency": "metal",
                                        "value_high": 8.33,
                                        "last_update": 1401486984,
                                        "difference": 0.22
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

then use `json_decode()` and access the data by iterating down to the values needed (your json should be saved to the variable `$json`):

```
$decoded = json_decode($json);

$value = $decoded->response->items->{'Mann Co. Supply Crate Key'}->prices->{'6'}->Tradable->Craftable[0]->value;
$value_high = $decoded->response->items->{'Mann Co. Supply Crate Key'}->prices->{'6'}->Tradable->Craftable[0]->value_high;
```

Comment: note: whenever you got object names in your `JSON` which aren't valid variable names - for example if the contain spaces or special characters - you can "encode" them with `{'my object name'}`. i needed to use this here for 'Mann Co. Supply Crate Key' and '6', cause numbers aren't valid object names as well.
PS: have fun playing TF2 ;)

Comment: I gave the same answer but a few minutes quicker than you.

Answer (score 0):

You get `$jsonString` from API, then use `$data = json_decode($jsonString, true);` to parse it to array. And you now just have to get needed variable from array.

To get needed variables:

`$value = $data['response']['items']['Mann Co. Supply Crate Key']['prices']['6']['Tradable']['Craftable']['value']`

and

`$value_high = $data['response']['items']['Mann Co. Supply Crate Key']['prices']['6']['Tradable']['Craftable']['value_high']`

Comment: Thats what  i cant do. Get the value from the array.

Comment: @Armageddon80 so you don't know how to get variable from array? Updated answer

Comment: @Armageddon80 try `var_dump` it. Maybe it's something wrong with response string?

Comment: this does work but i accidentally made a mistake. thanks

Comment: `Craftable` is an array: `$value_high = $data['response']['items']['Mann Co. Supply Crate Key']['prices']['6']['Tradable']['Craftable'][0]['value_high'];` - see my answer...

Answer (score 0):

With the PHP function `json_decode()` does a lot of work for you. Using

```
$data = json_decode($return_Value_from_api, true);
```

will save all data into the PHP variable `$data`. Once you have that, you can access the desired values from `$data`.

Notice that you should take a look at the structure of the JSON string.

```
$data = json_decode($str, true);

echo $data['response']['items']['Mann Co. Supply Crate Key'][ 'prices']['6']['Tradable']['Craftable'][0]['value'];
echo $data['response']['items']['Mann Co. Supply Crate Key'][ 'prices']['6']['Tradable']['Craftable'][0]['value_high'];
```

The problem that you didn't get the desired result is because the JSON array you gave, was incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$data = json_decode('{
    "response": {
        "success": 1,
        "current_time": 1401869275,
        "raw_usd_value": 0.245,
        "usd_currency": "metal",
        "usd_currency_index": 5002,
        "items": {
            "Mann Co. Supply Crate Key": {
                "defindex": [
                    5021
                ],
                "prices": {
                    "6": {
                        "Tradable": {
                            "Craftable": [
                                {
                                    "item_name": "Mann Co. Supply Crate Key",
                                    "quality": 6,
                                    "craftable": "Craftable",
                                    "tradable": "Tradable",
                                    "priceindex": 0,
                                    "defindex": [
                                        5021
                                    ],
                                    "value": 8.22,
                                    "currency": "metal",
                                    "value_high": 8.33,
                                    "last_update": 1401486984,
                                    "difference": 0.22
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            } } } }');

//print_r($data);

$craftable = $data->response->items->{'Mann Co. Supply Crate Key'}->prices->{'6'}->Tradable->Craftable;

foreach ($craftable as $c) {
    // prints "0"
    echo $c->priceindex, PHP_EOL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This JSON is very much nested so here is a solution to retrieve the data. I have used foreach to go to the inner element since there are some numeric indexes and assuming it might change so hard-coding the array index may fail if these numeric indexes are changed in some response

```
$str = 'your json string'

$json = json_decode($str,true);
foreach($json["response"]["items"]["Mann Co. Supply Crate Key"]["prices"] as $key=>$val){
    foreach($val["Tradable"]["Craftable"] as $k=>$v){
            echo $v["value"];
            echo "<br />";
            echo $v["value_high"];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = json_decode($JSON_STRING, true);
$value = $data['response']
              ['items']
              ['Mann Co. Supply Crate Key']
              ['prices']
              ['6']
              ['Tradable']
              ['Craftable']
              [0]
              ['value'];

$value_high = $data['response']
                   ['items']
                   ['Mann Co. Supply Crate Key']
                   ['prices']
                   ['6']
                   ['Tradable']
                   ['Craftable']
                   [0]
                   ['value_high'];

echo $value, PHP_EOL, $value_high, PHP_EOL;
```